# Responsive-grid-layout empty blocks when components are hidden

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm trying to hide component on ResponsiveReactGridLayout but a component is hide it create empty space because others components don't fill it.

I check if the checkbox linked to component is checked to hide or not.

```
      {this.isCheckedComponent("Component") ? (

        <div key="Component">
           Test
      </div>
      ) : (
        <div key="Component"  style={hideElement}></div>
      )}
```

I have also set size to zero but it's not working too.

```
const hideElement = {
  display: "none",
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
}
```

**It gives me following result:**

Above link corresponds to the display when component is not hiding.
[Not Hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOyed.png)

This one corresponds to the problem, you can see the space.
[Component Hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVCHA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an option could be a ternary condition with the next way:

https://codesandbox.io/s/yv4q5xl2wx

**Render function**:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.waffles &&
          this.state.waffles.map(waffle =>
            waffle.isChecked ? <div key={waffle.id}>{waffle.name}</div> : null
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The condition will be evaluated when it is true, it will show the component, and when the condition is false, it will show nothing.

Comment: It's not working, because ResponsiveReactGridLayout need a key. I get following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null".

Comment: @NicolasRoche I have generated this example so that you can keep an eye on it when a component you don't want to show it: https://codesandbox.io/s/yv4q5xl2wx (It's in my answer)

Comment: I have tried to check with state value (isChecked) but when I try to hide I get "Cannot read property 'key' of null". It's only linked to  ResponsiveReactGridLayout